# What is the influence of size of conductor on a repulsive force produced by a changing magnetic flux,according to Lenz's law?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

On Lenz's law, Wikipedia says:

> Faraday's law states that the EMF is also given by the rate of change
> of the magnetic flux where epsilon is the electromotive force (EMF)
> and $\phi_B$ is the magnetic flux.

$$\varepsilon = - \frac{-d \phi_B}{dt}$$

But is there also an influence of the size/shape of the receiving circuit on the EMF produced? I'm trying to recreate this at home using aluminium powder suspended in water but not seeing any movement, and many of the things I read on the internet seem to suggest that a larger conductor will work better, which would explain why I can't get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) "But is there also an influence of the size/shape of the receiving circuit on the EMF produced?"

$\Phi_B$ takes account of the size of the loop. For example, if the magnetic flux density has magnitude $B$ all over the loop, and is directed at angle $\theta$ to the loop, then
$$\Phi_B=BA\cos \theta$$
in which $A$ is the area of the loop.
Clearly a given change in $B$ will produce a larger change in $\Phi_B$ in a loop of larger area.

(b) You were expecting to see moment of the aluminium powder due to induced currents in the individual grains.

I believe that the grains were too small for this to happen. Here is an attempt to show this by the method of dimensions. Assume that the current is proportional to $\frac{dB}{dt} =\dot B$, and to unknown powers ($\alpha$ and $\beta$) of the resistivity, $\rho$, and radius, $r$. Thus
$$I=\dot B\rho^\alpha r^\beta$$
Equating SI units:
$$\text A=\text {T s}^{-1} (\Omega\ \text m)^\alpha\ \text m^\beta$$

Working towards expressing in SI base units:

$$\text A=\text {N A}^{-1}\text m^{-1} \text s^{-1}(\text{V A}^{-1} \text m)^\alpha\ (\text m)^\beta $$
So
$$\text A=\text {N A}^{-1}\text m^{-1} \text s^{-1}(\text{N m s}^{-1} \text A^{-2} \text m)^\alpha\ (\text m)^\beta $$
So
$$\text A=\text {kg m s}^{-2} \text{A}^{-1}\text m^{-1} \text s^{-1}(\text{kg m s}^{-2} \text{m s}^{-1} \text A^{-2} \text m)^\alpha\ (\text m)^\beta $$
Equating powers of $\text{kg}$:  0 = 1 +$\alpha$, so $\alpha$ = –1

Equating powers of $\text m$:  0 = 1 +3$\alpha$ + $\beta$, so $\beta$ = 2

Equating powers of $\text s$:  0 = –3 –3$\alpha$, so  $\alpha$ = –1

Equating powers of $\text A$:  1 = –1 –2$\alpha$, so $\alpha$ = –1

We see that the current is proportional to the square of the radius for a given rate of change of flux density. Therefore the currents in very small spheres will be very small indeed, and no doubt too small for the spheres to experience significant magnetic forces – which, incidentally, they would only do if the field were non-uniform.

Comment: I put a small amount of ultrafine Al powder (usually used as filler in casting resins) in a small test tube of water, swirled it around so its cloudy, and put a spinning halbach array up against the outside of the tube - I expected it to clear the cloudiness close to that side of the tube?

Comment: So you produced a changing magnetic field within the test tube and this would produce emfs within loops in the water. But I wouldn't expect any effects to be seen unless there were currents ('eddy currents') in these loops. There would be currents only if the water were electrically conducting, and the presence of suspended aluminium powder would not make it conduct well enough. That, I think, is why you saw no effects.

Comment: Tbh i hadnt thought it would have much effect on the water at all - i was hoping it would exert a repulsive force on the al dust in the water, and this would manifest as the water becoming clearer near the magnets as the al was pushed towards the other side?

Comment: I got the idea from videos of levitating quadcopters, which typically use such spinning Halbach arrays above a copper or aluminium plate - I get the impression it only works though if this plate is quite thick - using them on a really thin sheet sounds like it doesnt work as well - I want to know if that's true - if the thickness of the conductor being repulsed matters? As in that case maybe to make my aluminium dust move about in the water I'm going to need much stronger magnets?

Comment: If I've understood your set-up aright, you are expecting to induce eddy currents in water. So my original comment stands: the resistivity of the water is too high for there to be significant currents. Without the currents you won't get the forces you are looking for.

Comment: Thats not what im saying tho - by rotating the halbach array near the aluminium, and hence subjecting the aluminium to a changing magnetic field, im expecting to induce a current in the aluminium, which, by lens lenz's law,  then creates a magnetic field in opposition to the one which created it, i.e. the aluminium is then repulsed by the changing magnetic field of the halbach array - hence it is the aluminium, not the water, which should experience a repulsive effect. The water is incidental for this purpose - just a medium in which to suspend the aluminium to make the effect easier to see

Comment: Sorry. For some reason I missed your second comment. I  wonder if the grains are too small. I've just attempted a dimensional analysis and found that the current in a spherical grain is proportional to $r^3$, in which $r$ is the grain radius. [I assumed that the current was proportional to some power of the resistiivity, some power of $r$ and to $\frac{dB}{dt}$.]

Comment: That makes sense - can you please expand your answer with these equations and explain more fully why the effect is related to the 3rd power of radius in this case? Then i can mark it as the answer

Comment: Hi Philip, really interested in your answer - would be great if you can finish it please?

Comment: Hello Oliver. Sorry about the very long delay. In fact, if one assumes symmetry, it's quite easy to come to the same conclusion ($r^2$ dependency) by a complete analysis rather than a dimensional one.

Comment: OK many thanks Phillip - great answer, and lots to learn from it. One more thing - what does your last sentence mean about only experiencing magnetic force if field is non-uniform? Surely, besides a few specialised circumstances (like inside a solenoid of infinite length I believe), a magnetic field is always non-uniform?

Comment: You're right about the rarity of uniform magnetic fields, but I thought that I should point out that a current-carrying loop in a uniform magnetic field won't experience a *force* (only a torque – if its axis isn't aligned with the field).